# C# Console Application that Outputs a category based on input

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, arraylist

I have a task to develop a windows application that collects employee information: Name and Number of items sold as input and outputs a summary of information in a way that groups the Salesperson based on the number of items sold (below 50 items, 50-99 items, 100-199 items and a level above 199 items) See below. Can you help me with this code. Here is the code am working with thus far:

```
using System;

namespace L0002B
{
    public class Salesperson
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Quantity_Sold { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<Salesperson> Salesperson = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Salesperson>()
        {
             new Salesperson {Name="Donald Duck ",  Quantity_Sold=173},
             new Salesperson {Name="Mickey Mouse ",  Quantity_Sold=202},
             new Salesperson {Name="Snoopy  ",  Quantity_Sold=203},
        };
      
        }
        private static void Bonus(ref int Quantity_Sold)
        {
            if (Quantity_Sold >= 200)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Above 199 items");
            }
            else if (Quantity_Sold >= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("100-199 items");
            }
            else if (Quantity_Sold >= 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("50-99 items");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Below 50 items");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Bonus Report: " Bonus);
        }
    }
}
```

I want a output that provides a report that looks like this but I get a blank output instead.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsQpP.png)

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: So what if the value is, say, 120? It is higher than 50 so that branch is triggered, ignoring any else branch

Comment: Yes @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Your question still doesn't say anything about the issue you are facing. The logic of if and else can be fixed by the answer posted by ZoharPeled. What other issue you are facing?

Comment: I have added the error massages I got to the question. Mainly the system does not recognize the List Salesperson

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled, It fixed that. Now the ReportBonus line of code seems to generate the following error, " 'ReportBonus(ref int, int)': not all code paths return a value (CS0161) (L0002B)" AND " The local function 'ReportBonus' is declared but never used (CS8321) (L0002B)"

Comment: You're keep editing the question so my answer is no longer relevant. Please take the time to take the [tour], specifically [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your if conditions

1. You have the two conditions

   ```
   if (Quantity_Sold < 50)
      ...
   else if (Quantity_Sold > 50)
      ...
   ```

   None of the branches will get hit if `Quantity_Sold == 50`

   So you must use `<=` with one of these conditions or create an additional

   ```
   else if (Quatity_Sold == 50)
   ```

2. If you are comparing multiple thresholds with `>` using `if .. else if` you must start with the biggest value. If you are comparing with `<` you must start with the smallest value. Do not mix those comparators within the same `if .. else if .. else`

   - Your way: (assume `Quantity_Sold == 123`)

   ```
   if (Quantity_Sold > 50) 
      ...  //this will be hit because 123 > 50
   else if (Quantity_Sold > 100)
      ...  //this won't be hit anymore because first condition already is hit
   ```

   - Correct way:

   ```
   if (Quantity_Sold >= 100) 
      ...  // 100 .. maxint
   else if (Quantity_Sold >= 50)
      ...  // 50 .. 99
   else 
      ...  // 0 .. 49
   ```

   This will also solve the problem from the first case (ie what happens when `Quantity_Sold == 50`)

Comment: I have applied this correction and my output is still blank

Comment: @Hass  `Bonus()` is the only method in your code creating any output. But I don't see you calling it anywhere ...

Comment: I have edited the code in the question but then I get this err the I call it. "Syntax error, ',' expected (CS1003) (L0002B)"

Comment: What do you expect `Console.WriteLine("Bonus Report: " Bonus);` to do? First of all, you must separate the two parameters in the method call by `,`. Second, you will have to call your `Bonus` method for instace from the `Main` method and preferrably for each of the salespersons. TBH: If you are lacking fundamental programming skills (ie for instance how to call a method) I'm not sure I can help you. You should probably work through some basic programming tutorials first.